# Нейросети. Сигмоида при большой сумме

Tags: нейронные-сети

Я столкнулся со следующей проблемой: при умножении входного слоя на веса у меня получается огромное число(около 400(2500 входов)), из- за чего невозможно произвести функцию активации(пользуюсь сигмоидом((1/ 1+(2.72^(-400))), где (2.72^(-400)) практически равно 0, а в используемом яп вообще равно 0, следовательно 1/1+0 == 1). Ошибка? Где? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Все правильно, при большом “x” сигмоида стремится к 1, при большом отрицательном - стремится к 0.

Comment: Надо уметь сжимать данные и пользоваться разными функциями активации и биасами.

Comment: @Константин спасибо